# Insert new row with specific values

Tags: mysql, sql

In 1 table I need to insert specific rows with specific values, according to other tables values.

```
UPDATE item_properties2 AS P
INNER JOIN items ON items.id = P.item
INNER JOIN item_groups ON item_groups.idp = items.group_id 
SET P.nr = '0'
WHERE P.type = 1140614900 AND items_groups.idp = '1140503406';
```

This updates the table. But what I need is basically.

(`id`, `type`, `item`, `value`, `shows`, `nr`)  VALUES
(78173, 1336983282, 1352706945, 'test Laisvai pastatomas Sharp', 0, 1)

item_properties2.Id -  just row id,
`item_properties2.type` - connect to item_property_groups2.id ,
'item_properties2.item' this connects to item.id ,
item.id have another column which is item.group_id ,
item.group_id is connected to item_groups.id which have another column naked  item_groups.idp .

I need to only select items_groups.idp = '1140503406' . And basically i it should add rows in item_properties2 with with specific type value which i entered and only to models with specific item_properties2. item accord to item_groups.idp . I don't know how to do it.

Comment: MySQL [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) from the MySQL docs

Comment: Well this is simple Google serach results on how to [INSERT VALUES INTO MYSQL TABLE](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=INSERT+VALUES+IN+TO+MYSQL+TABLE&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a)

Here goes [Stack search results for insert values into mysql table](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=insert+values+into+mysql+table&submit=search) 

Both of these are very helpful to get some understanding.

Comment: @bluefeet : can we mark the question as a redundant?
hihi : You can see how table create and insert schema is working in this example: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6e8b)

Comment: Nonono its not simple. I to insert alot of rows according to aother table values.. i dont think its simple

Comment: Apology if it's not simple to you. Your question body text is quite not clear. So we have tried to 'guess' what you might want. Do you want to update an existing table(X) or insert into new table(Y) from another exisiting table(Z)?

Comment: @hihi you need to look at `INSERT INTO...SELECT FROM`

Comment: yes in existing table item_properties2, i need to add rows(multiple rows(about 1000)), yes i could do it easely and just add 40k rows to all the table, but i want to add specific amoun of rows according to item_groups.idp = '1140503406' , item_group.id is connected to item.group_id and in turn item.id is to item_properties2.item . Now it should add rows with specific item.id and that i get from item_groups.idp and item_properties2.type which i entered.

Answer (score 1):

there are some ways to insert a bulk of data from 2 tables into a newer table.

this can be done like this:

```
INSERT INTO item_properties2 (id, type, item, value, shows, nr)
SELECT Yid, Ytype,Yitem,Yvalue, Yshows, Ynr
FROM items
INNER JOIN item_groups ON item_groups.idp = items.group_id
WHERE  items_groups.idp = '1140503406'
```

Instead of using the VALUES tag, you will now call for a specific select statement. you only need to change the Y values above into your own column names.

Or you could place your input into a stored procedure 
the above query will run over your 2 tables and will insert the values that go with the where statement into the 3th table.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE sInput
    ( @val1 int, @val2 int, @val3 varchar(10))
    AS
    INSERT INTO MyTable(val1, val2, val3)
    VALUES(@val1, @val2, @val3)
    return
```

Comment: Into what column name you mean? i didnt understood, in items table there is no same column except that item_properties2.item = items.id

Comment: Can you specify if you're inserting new values or calculated values.
new values are values that you specify, calculated values are values from different tables.